# Go to windowed mode in Direct3D 9

Tags: winapi, directx, direct3d, direct3d9

I'm making a Direct3D app, and I can easily go from Windowed to Fullscreen mode using `IDirect3DDevice9::Reset` with new presentation parameters. However, when I use the same trick to go from fullscreen to windowed mode, the window has now lost its borders.

If I try doing `SetWindowLong` to set the window style to `WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU` (and then `SetWindowPos` with `SWP_FRAMECHANGED`), the window now gets its border, but the direct3d device no longer works. Resetting the device again doesn't work, and instead of `Reset(),` doing `Release()` then `SetWindowLong()` then `CreateDevice()` again, of course fails, as my managed resources are dependent on my device.

How do I make `IDirect3DDevice9::Reset` to go back to windowed mode, while creating a bordered window?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change the properties of the window:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);

if (new_pos_size)
{
    // if you want new position (pos_x, pos_y) and size (width, height)
    UINT flags = SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_SHOWWINDOW;
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, pos_x, pos_y, width, height, flags);
}
else
{
    UINT flags = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_SHOWWINDOW;
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, flags);
}
```

Next you have to release any resources you created in default pool - `D3DPOOL_DEFAULT` (it's better to use `D3DPOOL_MANAGED` if possible). If you don't, `IDirect3DDevice9::Reset` will fail.
Then you can reset the device and finally recreate any resources if needed. Make sure you set up `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` for `IDirect3DDevice9::Reset` correctly.